# Setting an onclick event to an empty span (an icon set in CSS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, onclick

I have inherited a codebase where icons are set across an image using some `<span>`s spread across an image. The spans look something like:

`<span class='circle_logo'></span>`

I need to trigger something to happen in the onclick event of these icons.

I have overcome this problem in the past by switching to `<button>`, but that does not work in this instance (it messes up the specific placement). I tried adding some `&nbsp;`s to the spans but it did not work, it seems like even if I add characters the clicks have to be on the actual pixels of the characters. Any thoughts?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `span` is visible somehow, just attach the handler using Javascript, like this:

```js
document.querySelector('.circle_logo').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

```css
.circle_logo {
  background-image: url("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/681cf17a49fa99ff9aa2289734aafac2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG");
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<span class='circle_logo'></span>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I'm not sure why an EventListener can listen to the span's potential clicks but an onClick cannot though....